# Creating a markdown table with ipinfo in Javascript

Tags: javascript, markdown

So I need to write a function in Javascript that uses ipinfo.io to get some info of a given IP address. The function needs to return this info in a markdown table. I was searching the internet for answers on how to do this and couldn't find anything... Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot :)
Tal

This is what I've got so far:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var ip = require("ip");

function queryIPInfo(ipAddr) {
try {
   if (!(ip.isV4Format(ipAddr) || ip.isV6Format(ipAddr)))
   throw("Not a valid IP address error");
}

catch (e) {console.log("Error: "+e);}

var xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlReq.open('GET', "https://ipinfo.io/"+ipAddr+"/json", true);
xmlReq.send();

xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xmlReq.readyState == 4 && xmlReq.status == 200) {
       var response = JSON.parse(xmlReq.responseText);
       // put the info from response in a markdown table and return it
    }
};
}
```

queryIPInfo(process.argv[2]);

Comment: Tables aren't part of the core Markdown spec.

Comment: I know that they aren't, but this is still my assignment :) It was given to me after I passed a job interview as another stage to test my abilities so I am guessing it is possible to create a table and return it. The question is how?

Comment: A [google search](https://www.google.be/search?q=markdown+table+javascript) gave me [this result](https://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/eJBoeK) which looks interesting. The rest depends on your abilities ;-)